# How can I redirect output from stdout into vim?

Tags: vim, pipe, stdout

I would like to view the output of `echo` in vim, and save to a file after having a look at it. I have tried `echo $PATH | vim`, but I get the following error:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

What can I do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/510890/how-do-i-redirect-command-output-to-vim-in-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How can I redirect output from stout into vim?

Your question has been answered on AskUbuntu.

The simplest solution is to add `-` to your command:

```
echo $PATH | vim -
```

> You can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (this also works with
>   applications that can't read from `STDIN`):
>
> ```
> vim <(ls -la)
> ```
>
> Or use `vim`'s function to read from `STDIN`:
>
> ```
> ls -la | vim -
> ```

Source [How do I redirect command output to vim in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/a/510907/376050), answer by [Chaos](https://askubuntu.com/users/185729/chaos)

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the `-` filename argument that instructs Vim to fill the buffer from stdin; cp. [`:help --`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--)

```
echo $PATH | vim -
```

Alternatively, you can use your shell's [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to create a temporary file descriptor and have Vim edit that "virtual" file.

```
vim <(echo $PATH)
```

Comment: If you're using Vim as a pager in place of less/more, try `| vim -R -` to disable the "Save changes?" prompt when you quit.